# Mouse wheel speed keeps resetting itself

Tags: windows-registry, mouse, windows-11, mouse-wheel

I am using Windows 11, and have two Logitech mouse peripherals (one bluetooth, one dongle) and a Kensington Trackball.

In Settings/Bluetooth & devices/Mouse I have set 'Multiple lines at a time' and 'Lines to scroll at a time' = 7.

The damn thing will reset to 28 at what would appear to be random times (at least nothing I have figured out yet).

- **How do I stop this behavior?**

I have found Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop - WheelScrollLines in the Registry editor but setting it there I get the same results.

One weird thing that I note is that one time after it had reset itself to 28 I restarted the PC, and it was set to 7 again (?!). i.e. *somewhere it had remembered the value of 7 after having reset itself*.

Edit>> sometimes it resets itself (I notice as scrolling is too fast again), but refreshing the registry editor will not reflect the change in value, it appears that I have to open the settings UI to trigger that.